# MYSQL query multiple comma separated strings

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have data stored in MYSQL database as shown below:

```
 id    t_id     type    color       Y        S       M          L   
  2    2606      2    Black DNA   1,5,8    4,2,6    7,3,9    10,11,12
```

I want the query to return like this with PHP:

Total:

```
Black DNA

1 (Y)  
2 (S)  
3 (M)  
4 (S)  
5 (Y)  
6 (S)  
7 (M)  
8 (Y)  
9 (M)  
10 (L)  
11 (L)  
12 (L)
```

I am using Joomla 2.7, Here is what I have tried in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(e.id) as id, e.color, GROUP_CONCAT(e.S) as small FROM  #__bl_equipment as e WHERE e.type = 4 AND e.t_id = 2606";
       $db->setQuery($query);
    $equip1 = $db->loadObjectList();


<table>

<?php foreach($this->equip1 as $equip){

echo '<tr><td>';
echo $equip->color;
echo '</td><td>';
echo $equip->small;
echo '</td></tr>';}

?>


</table>
```

Only result I have been able to get:

Black DNA   1, 2, 3

Comment: ok, and what is the question? what is your result, or what is not working as expected or do you get an error?

Comment: ...and that is why normalization was invented...

Comment: It will not return the 'S','M','L' next to each number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That would be too complicated with SQL (and doubt it's possible even)

I'd do the following
- Get Y, S, M and L columns
- Parse each using commas (so you get numbers) and turn them into arrays
- Sort each

So now you should have something like

y_numbers = [1,5,8]

s_numbers = [2,4,6]

m_numbers = [3,7,9]

l_numbers = [10,11,12]

Then inside a loop, look at first element of each array, find the smallest, print letter based on which array it is, iterate the pointer for that array... continue until you've exhausted all numbers

Comment: This is not the best answer.  It only perpetuates the ignorance of the OP.